# Unable to authenticate in django

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have been successfully using django's Authentication backend to authenticate users, and have a modified template system to do this. Everything seemed to work fine. Yesterday, while attempting to publish a production version of my site, I did two modifications:

1. Changed the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL from /appointments to /clinic Both of these are two seperate apps in my project.
2. I added `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` to redirect http to https.

After these, I pushed my commit to git development branch. I didnt notice any errors yesterday.

Today I attempted to run the development server, and noticed that I could not login. It was not recognizing my superuser login password. Hence I reset my password by using `manage.py changepassword` and `manage.py passwd`. However it still wouldnt login me in. There are no apparent errors shown (Debug is still set to True).

I created a new superuser, but even that login fails. In the frontend I get the error `Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.`.

When trying to login to the admin interface provided by django, I dont get any errors:

```
$ python3 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 17, 2018 - 16:26:29
Django version 2.1.2, using settings 'myappointments.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/clinic HTTP/1.1" 200 5469
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/clinic/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/css/datepicker.0.6.5.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/css/fontawesome.5.2.0.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/css/fullcalendar.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.structure.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/css/mytheme.css?dev= HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/registration/css/themedlogin.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/css/calcustomcolors.css?dev= HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js?dev= HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/js/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/js/notify.0.4.2.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/js/datepicker.0.6.5.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/js/search.js?dev= HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/lib/moment.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/js/fullcalendar.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:31] "GET /appointments/static/appointments/js/appointment.js?dev= HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:32] "GET /appointments/static/clinic/icons/health-sign.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:39] "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:39] "GET /clinic HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:40] "GET /clinic/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:40] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/clinic HTTP/1.1" 200 5469
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:44] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:44] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1862
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:44] "GET /appointments/static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 8192
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:50] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:50] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[17/Oct/2018 16:26:50] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1862
```

I should probably mention that on my development machine, I use the local python3 version while on production I use a virtualenv.

Comment: Have you set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True`? This won’t work for the development server since it is http only.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should have different settings for your production and development environment. Take a look at this structure. Here is a nice article about it. [multiple settings](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2017/07/03/django-tip-20-working-with-multiple-settings-modules.html)

```
mysite/
 |-- mysite/
 |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |-- settings/
 |    |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- base.py
 |    |    |-- ci.py
 |    |    |-- development.py
 |    |    |-- production.py
 |    |    +-- staging.py
 |    |-- urls.py
 |    +-- wsgi.py
 +-- manage.py
```

For example you can put SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True on production.py file. The idea is to have settings acoording to your environments needs.